# Add contact to ActiveSync on Samsung phone

Tags: contacts, active-sync

I have two Samsung phones connect to my Exchange email using ActiveSync.

When I manually add a contact they are stored on the phone and not ActiveSync, how can I set the default storage mechanism to be ActiveSync?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure contact syncing is enabled for the particular activesync account. You can check by going to *Settings > Accounts*. Select your activesync account and ensure Contacts are selected. You can also check accounts settings from the contact app by opening the menu. Then try creating a new contact, it should prompt you to choose a destination (phone, email etc).